# Cons for defining logger non-static

Tags: java, logging

Comments for this answer [How do you reduce Java logging boilerplate code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212697/how-do-you-reduce-java-logging-boilerplate-code#212753) strongly suggest not to use loggers as instance member variables. I can think of two negative side-effects:
1) superclass logs with the subclass's logger
2) object cannot be serialized (unless marked transient)

But if serializing is not necessary and logging with subclass name is not a problem, is there anything else why it should be avoided? I think it reduces boilerplate code and avoids copy-paste errors while copying logger variable definition from one class to another. Even Spring framework (which I believe has very good coding standards) uses this method.

Answer (score 9):

If your Logger is an instance member instead of static, the Logger has to be retrieved every time a new object is created. Albeit this overhead is probably insignificant, but it's one disadvantage.

From a design perspective, Loggers aren't really a property of an object, since they're usually meta-information about your system rather than business information within the system itself. A `Logger` isn't really part of something like a `Car` object in the same way an `Engine` or a `Transmission` is. Tying Loggers to objects as members (in most cases) doesn't make sense semantically more than anything.

Comment: Some loggers have a caching mechanism. Log4j uses the `LogManager` class for caching loggers, hence the overhead of using static and non static loggers is same.

Comment: @VarunAchar - Right - the memory overhead of the actual `Logger` instance is usually cached. What I was mostly getting at here is that the *reference* to the manager or logger instance would be repeated across all instances if the `Logger` wasn't `static`, and there'd still have to be a call to retrieve the `Logger` (i.e. from the cache) for every instance that gets created. Again, probably insignificant, but notable.

Comment: And also, it does use more memory. The field itself (reference to the Logger object) is 4 bytes (at least), which are to be stored in every instance.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at these pages discussing the subject:

- [SLF4j FAQ: Should Logger members of a class be declared as static?](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#declared_static)
- [Commons Wiki: When Static References to Log objects can be used](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/COMMONS/Logging+StaticLog)

Answer (score 2):

The major difference asides from the Superclass logging with subclass name, of course, is that you'll have one `Logger` object per member of your class.  Depending on how many classes are using logging, this can be a huge amount of Loggers, so memory bloat may be an issue.

Plus from an abstract point of view, the logger really does belong to the class and can be shared between all instances, rather than each instance needing its own private copy, so it makes sense to declare it as static.  Flipping your question around, what advantages does it have to making it non-static?  (Being able to pass `getClass()` into the `getLogger()` call instead of passing in the class constant is the only thing I can think of, and that's such a tiny thing).

Comment: Log4j (I presume other logging frameworks also) holds a pool of loggers. So only one instance with the same name is created. So memory consumption is the same as with static loggers.

Answer (score 1):

Another, probably minor con: wasted memory, especially when you have lots of instances, each one with its own logger

Comment: Log4j (I presume other logging frameworks also) holds a pool of loggers. So only one instance with the same name is created. So memory consumption is the same as with static loggers.

Comment: if this is con then better to use singelton

Comment: @martsraits: No, because your class holds a new reference (pointer) to the pooled instance

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging an error where you see a message generated by the `SuperClass` class when the error is really being logged in the `SubClass` class. I've seen several situations where developers create a `LoggingUtils` class which generates messages which generally duplicate the things which are already baked-in by the logging framework.

The only real situation I see for using a shared logging instance is something like the Apache commons HttpClient logger `httpclient.wire` which is shared between several classes for logging the contents of the requests and responses sent through the client. This particular logging situation does not log information for the actual implementation of the package, it logs information about the whole http "transaction".

Answer (score 0):

One of the main concerns are at cleaning memory instances. Even you don't create objects of a class, since you use static instances of logger there will be references to those objects.

Also as apache says, this keeps references so they won't freed once after used.

[Apache Wiki says like this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/COMMONS/Logging+StaticLog)

The use of the static qualifier can be beneficial in some circumstances. However in others it is a very bad idea indeed, and can have unexpected consequences.

The technical result of using static is obvious: there is only one Log reference shared across all instances of the class. This is clearly memory efficient; only one reference(4 or 8 bytes) is needed no matter how many instances are created. It is also CPU-efficient; the lookup required to find the Log instance is only done once, when the class is first referenced.